# Types for recursive array.map in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple case which transforms a nested string array to a nested number array, no flatting

```js
const strArr = ["1", "2", ["3", "4"], "5"];

function mapToNumber(item: string | Array<string>): number | Array<number> {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return item.map(mapToNumber); // line Hey
    } else {
        return Number(item);
    }
}
console.log(strArr.map(mapToNumber));
```

However TS yells at me: `Type '(number | number[])[]' is not assignable to type 'number | number[]'`. Then I changed line `Hey` to `return item.map<number>(mapToNumber)`, doesn't work.
Function overloading came to my mind, I gave it a try:

```js
const isStringArray = (arr: any): arr is Array<string> => {
    return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}

function mapToNumber(item: string): number;
function mapToNumber(item: Array<string>): Array<number>;
function mapToNumber(item: any) {
    if (isStringArray(item)) {
        return item.map<number>(mapToNumber);
    } else {
        return Number(item);
    }
}

console.log(strArr.map(mapToNumber));
```

Even though I added the custom type guard, still doesn't work.

The logic is quite simple, but how can I define the correct type for this simple case? [The playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBBe8YF4YG0BEBGbANDNgEyFbYDM52ALNgLpHYCsjA3ALABQPAZgFcwwKAEtwMALYBDAA4AVEADkBkgEYBTeLgAUoqBskAuOFHiiwAcxgAfGMnjSAngB4EFywD4AlCbCrNVDsHZxd-dS1PGABvHhh4mFE+GB0QpwA6UQg0vQNJb28YuISS+A0oAXgwRLz0mVkdesUVCO1vLm4SgF8YDQAbCA0izpKEsoqqmBbA3MN24viuniXuUEgQPo10vpBLHQQHOrlGuWaArVwCjp416ESIAGUzDzT0FOkUE2kwJ18YD9QWXsKFC7isUTQUViI3i40q1TSmWyIKcOgBhQAZBj-ih0hoAG5aVH6QzoKJQJyyDQgZIkyToNAYbBgyzYebcFb8IQicTVJrKc7wWbGUzmKx-cKBDqCYRiCT86ZaYUmNJuZ7gv6qyWRaXcuV804C1rK-4-QrQkpJFJZJ5iyw5OkFYajMbleE1QxHWRhQWeE4KI2BdndXoDIYWl0wOGTRVCx0dbrLHg3cAQDZbHZ7A64+r+s6tK7J7gynnyw2xygueS9AAeBjAABMIKKPLZgY5XCzPH66SZ5H9qxo6xpG82WTAAPwwbWoFUon2tKELRLJVIopEOvJOiMu6PVOlevOBrSUYMJHr9QbOyN7qaC4VnxbLIA)

*Edit*:

I gave generics a try, still doesn't work

```js
function mapToNumber3<T extends string | Array<string>>(item: T): T extends string ? number : Array<number> {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return item.map(mapToNumber3);
    } else {
        return Number(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to just define a type: `type NestedArray<T> = T | NestedArray<T>[]` 
to represent a nested array of type T.
Then, you just type your variables in your original functions, and it should work.

```
type NestedArray<T> = T | NestedArray<T>[]

const strArr: NestedAr

ray<string> = ["1", "2", ["3", "4"], "5"];

const isStringArray = (arr: any): arr is Array<string> => {
    return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}

function mapToNumber(item: NestedArray<string>): NestedArray<number> {
    if (isStringArray(item)) {
        return item.map(mapToNumber);
    } else {
        return Number(item);
    }
}

console.log(strArr.map(mapToNumber));
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that you can use [f-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification):

```js
const strArr = ["1", "2", ["3", "4"], "5"];


const mapToNumber = (item: string) => parseInt(item, 10)

const isString = (item: unknown): item is string => typeof item === "string"
const isStringArray = (arr: any): arr is Array<string> => Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(isString)


const map = <
    N extends number,
    Elem extends `${N}` | Array<Elem>,
    T extends Array<T | Elem>,
    >(arr: [...T]): Array<unknown> => {
    return arr.map((item) => {
        if (isStringArray(item)) {
            return item.map(mapToNumber);
        }
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            return map(item)
        }
        if (isString(item)) {
            return mapToNumber(item)
        }
        return item
    })

}

const result = map(["1", "2", ["3", "4", ['6', ['7']]], "5"])
```

`T extends Array<T | Elem>` - T is a recursive generic

The safest approach is to return `Array<unknown>` since you don't know the deepnes of the array
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBBe8YF4YG0BEBGbANDNgEyFbYDM52ALNgLpHYCsjA3ALABQPPokWAFsAhgAcAKiAByAVyEAjAKaoMACgCWUJUIBccKPA1gA5gEp0APhhiR8CEoCSYKJu1CiuAAxm%203AdAwGhAAyobGJugwbjr6smAA1mAgAO5gZvpaOkEQBkamVjBQAJ5iSiAAZkHu6GgY2AgR2PzggcFh%20SbI8CLFUWp28PoiYMUZMIM5MN29ADyNptZo1jPFAHTBqwMoFgBkuxMoa0oAbirFmqHhpr68dwHC4lGzPDBvMNIwSgAe2mAAJrkwPJlPACK93gBRAA22R%20f0BMAABgASADe0gAvkiYAAfaYoOYwnSWcHcd4wCRfX5KAG5VazKn44lCUkQt6WbZDLBrXkSBjjBnxJKpMBLaxo9kweBKKCyeBgQ7wNaiMRqGJCCzLGCS8kU94aKqXDoRLZZTUWXX663S2XyxXmlXiNSqqRyRQqMxcPXWzFSimG6KrDYQM3uMyW-02mVyhUwVUa242mB%20n36wPG64mRORtPJmP2%20PiN0glSJqNvVP5u1x81SzG3HiplqCW0QWTQ2AYBM4fDMMhEHDUZj0QcAcgAbGPxwB2McMBfMNgCoA)

It is relatively easy to create recursive data structure type in typescript. See [here](https://catchts.com/flatten), but it is hard to use it as a return type in function

Comment: Seems like @jeremynac's answer is way more simple but this answer is more general , defining a `NestedArray<T>` already suffices, why bother using `T extends Array<T | Elem>`

Comment: Sure. I had several versions of the code. Just did not polished it

Answer (score 0):

**More information on [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) (basically, there's no good way to currently do this sadly).** Proposal for what you want [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).

I think you just have to use `as` for now:

```
const strArr = ["1", "2", ["3", "4"], "5"];

function mapToNumber(item: string | string[]): number | number[] {
  if (typeof item === 'string') {
    return Number(item);
  } else {
      return item.map(mapToNumber) as number[]; // Here
  }
}

console.log(strArr.map(item => mapToNumber(item)));
```

Your example with overloading technically works if you add one more overload. Up to you if you think it's worth all the effort.

```
const strArr = ["1", "2", ["3", "4"], "5"];

const isStringArray = (arr: any): arr is Array<string> => {
  return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(item => typeof item === "string");
}

function mapToNumber(item: string): number;
function mapToNumber(item: string[]): number[];
function mapToNumber(item: string | string[]): number | number[]; // Add this
function mapToNumber(item: any) {
  if (isStringArray(item)) {
      return item.map<number>(mapToNumber);
  } else {
      return Number(item);
  }
}

console.log(strArr.map(mapToNumber));
```